# Is there a modern replacement for the strict-concurrency package?

Tags: haskell, concurrency

Real World Haskell mentions the [strict-concurrency library](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/concurrent-and-multicore-programming.html) that provides strict versions of Chan and MVar. That sounds handy, but unfortunately the library doesn't compile with recent GHC ([it's limited to base<4.6](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/strict-concurrency)). What do people use nowadays?

Comment: My usual approach is to (nicely) harass the library devs until they update the library. Sometimes it's a matter of letting them know that someone still cares about the library. In this case, it appears the problem might be as simple as changing the `base` dependency in the cabal file, noted [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/strict-concurrency-0.2.4.1/revisions/).

Comment: @Eric : I tried fixing the dependencies, but it turns out they are there for a reason. If you look closely you'll see they actually made them more restrictive, not the contrary.

Comment: Ah, I see that now. In that case, why not ping Don? He can update the library or tell you why he isn't bothering these days and give you an alternative.